# Enum flag and None value

Tags: c#, enums, enum-flags

I was playing around with the `SslPolicyErrors` enum and noticed the following behavior:

```cs
SslPolicyErrors error = SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors
                      | SslPolicyErrors.None
                      | SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch;

Console.WriteLine(error.HasFlag(SslPolicyErrors.None));
Console.WriteLine(error.HasFlag(SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors));
Console.WriteLine(error.HasFlag(SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch));
```

I would expect the first print for the None flag to be `false`, but to my surprise all three prints were `true`:

```
True
True
True
```

So I looked up the source and found this:

```cs
    [Flags]
    public enum SslPolicyErrors
    {
        None                          = 0x0,
        RemoteCertificateNotAvailable = 0x1,
        RemoteCertificateNameMismatch = 0x2,
        RemoteCertificateChainErrors  = 0x4
    }
```

Which was exactly what I expected initially, but I don't understand how an instance can both have the None flag and at the same time one or more other flags.

Comment: `0 & 0 == 0` checks out.

Comment: @YongShun, the article doesn't go into the specifics of the zero flag. @ProgrammingLlama, I understand that that is what the underlying check does. But How could the check `if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)` ever be safe? (From the ms docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback?view=net-7.0)

Comment: `sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None` isn't the same check as `error.HasFlag(SslPolicyErrors.None)`. The equality check will only return `true` if it is exactly equal to 0, whereas the `HasFlag` check will always return `true` for `None`.

Comment: @Jurgy HasFlag checks for one flag, checking for equality to zero checks that no (non-zero) flags are set.

Comment: Oh right, looked right over that. Of course! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Question was answered in the comments but for completeness sake I will answer it myself.

[From the docs itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=net-7.0#remarks):

> The `HasFlag` method returns the result of the following Boolean
> expression.
>
> `thisInstance And flag = flag`
>
> If the underlying value of `flag` is zero,
> the method returns `true`. If this behavior is not desirable, you can
> use the `Equals` method to test for equality with zero and call `HasFlag`
> only if the underlying value of flag is non-zero, as the following
> example illustrates.

So for zero flags you have to do `flag == Flags.None` instead of `flag.HasFlag(Flags.None)`